# Sed: Decreasing speed of data processing

Tags: sed, gnuplot

I have large files (10-20 GB) which I preprocess with Sed before I plot the data using Gnuplot. The plots are saved as .png image. The `data` file consists of `images` matrices of size `matrix_size x matrix_size`. The `data` file for two (`images=3`) matrices of size `matrix_size=2` looks like:

```
 1 2
 3 2
 1 5
 3 4
 5 2
 2 3
```

I use Sed to extract each matrix of the `data`  file. At the beginning this happens really fast and my script produces one image per second. But after a while the time increases up to 25 seconds per image. Why is this the case? Here is my code:

```
unset border
unset key
unset xtics
unset ytics
unset ztics
unset colorbox

set autoscale fix
set size ratio -1

file = 'data'
matrix_size = 1000
images = 1000

sizeX = matrix_size
sizeY = matrix_size
set xrange [1:matrix_size]
set yrange [1:matrix_size]
set terminal png size sizeX, sizeY

getMatrix(fileName, n, i) = sprintf("<sed -n '%d,%dp;%dq' '%s'", (i-1)*n + 1, i*n, i*n+1, fileName)

do for [i=1:images]{
    t0 = strftime('%s', time(0))    
    set output sprintf('%05d_%s.png', i, file)
    plot getMatrix(file, matrix_size, i) matrix with image
    t1 = strftime('%s', time(0))
    print(sprintf('%d %d', t1-t0, i))
}
```

Here is the time it takes in seconds for every image to plot. At the beginning very fast and then slower and slower:

[image]

Comment: according to your plot output the processing is getting slow after 700000 line, is that right? If `getMatrix()` function is written by you , then you should understand what I mean

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Sorry, I don't see what you mean.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I do not see how your question helps to solve my problem. I did write the code with the help of another post from me.

Comment: I asked about details of processing logic - cause that matters. But it seems that you don't have much idea how the process really goes

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I read the Sed documentation to write the getMatrix() function. Other posts also suggest similar approaches to handle large data files when working with Sed. Probably I did not understand everything perfectly but I think here is the place to ask for help.

Comment: I can ask one more time: After **what amount of lines** from the file `data` the process start getting slow down?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest after about 750000. It's hard to say since the time it takes to produce one image oscillates quite a lot.

Comment: I'll try to emulate the current processing with a test file of about 1000000 lines

Comment: For each image your `sed` command starts at the beginning of the file, then has to read it up to the desired image data, and then exits. It makes sense that this takes longer for images whose data is toward the end of the file. The sudden increases in the time it takes to process the file might be related to filesystem caching.

Comment: @Samuel, unfortunately, the current plot script doesn't display any plot window at my terminal, only prints time points. gnuplot version: `gnuplot 5.0 patchlevel 3`. I've tried ...

Comment: @user8153, as a man who are using `gnuplot` actively, do you have any idea why does the above script not display any plot images/windows on `gnuplot 5.0 patchlevel 3` (`Ubuntu 16.04`)? thanks

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest My script does not plot the time per image actively. It just outputs the data to the console and can be redirected to a file by using `gnuplot code_from_above 2> time.dat`. Then it can be plotted by opening gnuplot and the command `plot 'time.dat' u 2:1`

Comment: Perhaps splitting the file into smaller parts and then concatenating the results might prevent what looks like a lack of memory.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Rather than displaying the actual images the code creates many individual files 00000_data.png, 00001_data.png, and so forth. The timing information is written to stdout, which can be captured and then displayed separately.

Comment: Use `awk`, or `Perl` or similar to make a single pass through the file and split it into your 1000 images, each in a separate file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you use `split` to extract all your matrices to individual files, up front, in a single pass:

```
split -a 4 -d -l matrix_size data matrix-
```

That will put each matrix in a separate file called `matrix-0000`, `matrix-0001` if I understood your file format.

Comment: Your solution is very simple and my gnuplot script runs now extremely fast. It took about 1.1 seconds per image. Great!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments the `sed` command always has to start at the beginning of the datafile to search for the i-th frame, which can take a long time. I do not know if one can avoid that while using a looping construct within gnuplot. However, you can use `awk` (and presumably also `sed`) to go through the datafile in a single pass, and insert the `gnuplot` commands to set up and finish a frame at the right line numbers. I am curious if something like this would work for you; if it does that I assume it will not show the slowing-down at later frames:

```
unset border
unset key
unset xtics
unset ytics
unset ztics
unset colorbox

set autoscale fix
set size ratio -1

matrix_size = 1000

sizeX = matrix_size
sizeY = matrix_size
set xrange [-0.5:matrix_size-0.5]
set yrange [-0.5:matrix_size-0.5]
set terminal png size sizeX, sizeY

file = "data"
load sprintf("< cat %s | awk \'\
    BEGIN {i = 0;} \
    NR %% %d == 1 \{ \
      print \"print \\\"Creating image \" i \" \\\"\"; \
      print \"set output \\\"%s_\" i \".png\\\"\"; \
      print \"plot \\\"-\\\" matrix with image\"; \
    } \
    {print;} \
    NR %% %d == 0 { \
      print \"e\\ne\"; \
      i = i+1; \
    } \
  \'", file, matrix_size, file, matrix_size)
```

### Explanation

As requested, here is a brief explanation what this code does. As an example, let's say the file `data` contains 2 matrices, each of size 3x3:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
10 11 12
16 17 18
13 14 15
```

The command

```
cat data | awk 'NR % 3 == 1 {print "plot \"-\" matrix with image";} {print;} NR % 3 == 0 {print "e\ne";}'
```

read this file and creates the following output:

```
plot "-" matrix with image
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
e
e
plot "-" matrix with image
10 11 12
16 17 18
13 14 15
e
e
```

This is valid gnuplot code. It does so by inserting the line `plot "-" matrix with image` before lines 1 and 4, and the two `e` after lines 3 and 6. You could save this output to a file and let gnuplot run it, or you can run the code directly from inside gnuplot using the `load sprintf("< cat data | awk ....` construction. This is nice because you only have a single script, but you have to be careful to escape quotation and backslash characters. The above code also adds a counter so that a new filename is used for every image (and the `set output data_FRAMENUMBER.png` line for every image).

It is probably easier to take the big `data` file and split it up into many smaller ones, one for each frame. However, if you cannot do that for some reason (it can be annoying to have thousands of files in a directory), or if you have to keep the one big file around for some other kind of processing, then this is a reasonable solution.

Comment: Your solution is really fast. It takes on average 1.14 seconds to print an image. But I have no idea whats going on there. Can you please explain some details of your code?

Comment: @Samuel I added a brief explanation to my answer.