# Efficient ways to make gifs in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have a data file that has the following format:

```
#x y z
 0 0 0   //initial block
 . . .   
 0 0 0

 . . .     //more blocks

 10 10 10  //last block
 .  .  .
 10 10 10
```

The file contains the positions of N atoms, and is comprised of many blocks, where each block is separated by `\n` and contains the positions of these atoms at a given time step. There are about 200,000 blocks. I want to create an animated gif of this data file, effectively presenting how the atoms move in time.

The following is a working code that produces what I want:

```
set terminal pngcairo
set style line 1 lc rgb 'blue' pt 7
unset key
set xrange [-2:17]
set yrange [-2:17]
set zrange [-20:20]
system('mkdir -p png')

m=0
max= 5000  #need to increase this limit, but set as is for testing purposes
i=200      #
do for [ii=0:max] {
    m=m+1
    set output sprintf('png/pos%03.0f.png',m)
    plot 'position.dat' every :::i::i u 2:3 w p ls 1
    i=i+1
    unset output
}
```

This code produces many `png` files which I then compile as a gif using GIMP.

**Question:** This whole process takes a very very long time right now. I am seeking for better/more efficient ways to do it.

Comment: `set terminal gif animate`

Comment: I was hoping the master would help me! Is everything else correct, and just change the terminal? Also, will this speed up the process or only cut on the time taken by GIMP?

Comment: You must set the output only once, every plot is appended as new animation frame

Comment: So set terminal to `gif animate`, and take `set output` outside the for loop, keep everything else as is?

Comment: I think so, you try it!

Comment: So it works, but it's not any faster. Maybe I just have to deal with this computation time? The issue is that right now I am simulating 50 atoms, where in actuality I would like to simulate 100-200. In that case, it would take perhaps over 12 hours to create this gif!

Comment: One improvement could be to use a file format which allows you to directly access the desired block. Like you have it, gnuplot must read the complete file until it encounters the respective block (see also).

Comment: Will it help if I delete blocks as I plot them? That way gnuplot would always be plotting the very first block in the file. Of course, I'll make a copy of the original file so I don't lose data.

Comment: Except maybe there isn't a way to delete rows of data in a file from gnuplot

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47056099/sed-decreasing-speed-of-data-processing/47085729#47085729) for tips on how loop through large data files efficiently. But perhaps you can simply reduce the size of your data? If you have 200000 frames, and make an animation with, say, 30 frames per second, the animation would be 111 minutes long.

Comment: Also, for a complicated visualization like 100-200 atoms moving around in three dimensions I would recommend a special-purpose application like [VMD](http://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Research/vmd/).

Comment: @user8153 thanks for the VMD suggestion.